# How can I sort a data frame by groups?

Tags: r, data

I am using R. I have a data frame with "year , price, mileage" columns. I want to group the df by year first and then sort each group by mileage. How can I do this?

Comment: You should consider asking this sort of question over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), not on Data Science. Additionally, you should share what you have already tried in solving this problem. Where exactly did you go wrong?

Comment: Order by year, mileage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'dplyr' package in R is ideal for these types of data manipulation tasks. The arrange function for example can group a dataframe by a certain column, and then sort by another column. For example:

```
arrange(df, desc(mileage), group_by = year)
```

See [arrange](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) for documentation on the arrange function, and [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) for the dplyr package description.